Normalization of Grocery Shop Database: From 1NF to 3NF
In a grocery shop, customers buy items, and the products have categories. The TotalQuantity represents the stock of products.
1NF:
OrderProduct (OrderID, OrderDate, OrderTime, CustomerID, CustomerName,
    CustomerAddress, CustomerNumber, CustomerEmail, ProductID, ProductName,
    UnitPrice, TotalQuantity, CategoryID, CategoryName, CategoryDescription)

What is correct and incorrect in my 2NF and 3NF?
2NF:
Order (OrderID, OrderDate, OrderTime, CustomerID)
Customer (CustomerID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber, Email)
Product (ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, CategoryID, TotalQuantity)
Category (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
OrderItem (OrderID, ProductID)

3NF:
Order (OrderID, OrderDate, OrderTime, CustomerID)
Customer (CustomerID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber, Email)
Product (ProductID, ProductName, UnitPrice, CategoryID, TotalQuantity)
Category (CategoryID, CategoryName, Description)
OrderItem (OrderID, ProductID)
ProductCategory (ProductID, CategoryID)


Or both 2NF and 3NF should be the same?

3NF looks good to me. A question, if a customer buys (say) two boxes of cake mix, would that be two OrderItems, or should there be one OrderItem with a Quantity column?

@PhilipKelley Yes, adding Quantity column is needed right to OrderItem?

Referencing @Doug's answer, it depends on what is being tracked: the quantity to include in the order, or the quantity available to be sold. Your "TotalQuantity" sounds like "available to be sold", but that's inventory management and a complex issue in it's own right, and still leaves the question of how to track quantity sold per order.
Also, Doug is right, CategoryId does not belong in the Product table.

On your 3NF model, it might not be ideal to have a CategoryID field in the Product. The ProductCategory table allows for a many-to-many relationship between products and categories. The Category(s) associated with a particular product will be reckoned from the association table--not from an actual property of product itself.
The same goes for the field TotalQuantity in the product table. Quantity isn't a property of product. A customer may order as many of the products as they want in your orders--that quantity is stored in the orderItem table.
Here's an ERD that might be useful:
This data model allows for a customer to have more than one address and more than one phone number. The addresses/phone numbers can be "deactivated" by setting their deleted datetime value to something non-trivial. This many-to-one relationship is begging for other dimensions to enrich the objects (such as phone-type, address-type, etc.). Those details are purposefully left out of this illustration but could easily be added.
This model also understands that a product's set price isn't necessarily what is charged in an order. This is the reason for the extended_price field in order_item. Further, unless there is a unique constraint on order_id, product_id in the order_item table, the scenario where a customer buys one at regular price and then another at half-off is supported.


Thanks, @Doug. When designing tables in a DBMS, do we need to ensure they are in 3NF? And 2NF is correct, right?

It looks like the only really difference between your 2nf and 3nf models is that in 3nf, Products are allowed to be associated with more than one category. So, in the 2nf, I see the same issue where [TotalQty] is in the product table and not in the OrderItem table where it should be.
And just a semantic nit pic: I wouldn't name a column of a table [total_qty]. Especially an order line item table. The field is simply a quantity. Totals come later in reports. Totals are usually derived rather than persisted.

I'm not sure if that answered your question. In any DBMS, you are at liberty to follow or violate normalization principles as you wish. It's usually best, especially at the beginning, to stick to normalization principles closely unless you feel you have a compelling reason to violate.
If you're not yet using ERDs (entity relation diagrams), such as the one I used above, it would be a good idea to start. Even on paper, an ERD is a good way to keep you from plunging full speed into creating a mess.

Doug's answer is a good one. I am not sure from your initial description, whether or not a product can be related to more than one category. If it can, then the separate product/category table is the correct way to go, but if a product can only have one category, then having the category id in the product table would be correct and the the product/category table would be unnecessary.
You may also wish to consider what should happen if someone orders 10, but only 8 are in stock.
